# React hooks problem with passing value || defaultValue and updating counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, use-state

Find below example codes and screenshot.

Two questions:

1. `counter` isn't updating correctly, is it allowed to write something like `setCounter((prev) => { return { counter: prev.counter - value || 1 }});`?
2. `setCounter(counter + value || 1)` What is the correct way for this
   to work, use 1 in cases when an actually value is missing?

Find below example codes and screenshot.

```
const Counter = (props) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleCounterChange = (action, value) => {
    switch (action) {
      case "+":
        setCounter(counter + value || 1);
        break;
      case "-":
        setCounter(counter - value || 1);
        break;
      default:
        setCounter(counter + value || 1);
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.Counter}>
      <CounterOutput value={counter} />
      <CounterControl
        label="+"
        clicked={() => handleCounterChange("+")}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="-"
        clicked={() => handleCounterChange("-")}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="+ 5"
        clicked={() => handleCounterChange("+", 5)}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="- 5"
        clicked={() => handleCounterChange("-", 5)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with `setCounter(counter + value || 1);` is that JS will try to first compute `counter + value` *then* the boolean test. So for example if your `counter` value is `1` and you subtract a value of `1`, the result is `0`, which is falsey, so then `1` will be saved as the new value of `counter`. This probably isn't what you want.

```js
console.log(100 + undefined || 1); // expect 101 but result is 1
console.log(1 + -1 || 1); // expect 0 but result is 1
```

You can group the precedence though, i.e. `counter + (value || 1)`.

```js
console.log(100 + (undefined || 1)); // 101
```

If you are simply wanting to provide a default value of 1 for `value` then you can do that in the signature. If `value` is undefined it will be assigned the value of `1`. And use a functional state update.

```
const handleCounterChange = (action, value = 1) => {
  switch (action) {
    case "+":
      setCounter(counter => counter + value);
      break;
    case "-":
      setCounter(counter => counter - value);
      break;
    default:
      setCounter(counter => counter + value);
      break;
  }
};
```

A side note about this "reducer" type pattern is to return the existing state if the action isn't one you specifically handle.

```
const handleCounterChange = (action, value = 1) => {
  switch (action) {
    case "+":
      setCounter(counter => counter + value);
      break;
    case "-":
      setCounter(counter => counter - value);
      break;
    default:
      // ignore, i.e. don't update state at all
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of excellent refactors proposed here. I'd definitely want to read through the suggestions and do a refactor.

As for the cause of your unpredictable counter, assuming the click arguments are getting into your state updating function, there's an order-of-operations issue. Consider this situation.

### Value is `undefined`

From the way the code above is written, when value is `undefined`, we're hoping to add a `value` number to the `counter` state. Due to order-of-operations, that's not what's happening. This bug hides in plain sight because often `value` and `counter` are both `1`, so it seems like state isn't changing.

```
> let value = undefined
undefined
> let counter = 1
undefined
> counter + value || 100
100
```

That last statement says "add up counter plus `undefined`" which is `NaN` and also falsy. The result in that case will always be the other side of the 'or' statement, `100`.

Using parens changes the order of operations, and creates the desired behavior.

```
> counter + (value || 100)
101
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, per se, but don't overcomplicate your code with that extra unnecessary function. Your logic is so simple, adding that extra function makes it more complex to read and adds weird logic (what's the default for?)

```js
  return (
    <div className={classes.Counter}>
      <CounterOutput value={counter} />
      <CounterControl
        label="+"
        clicked={() => setCounter(state => state+1)}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="-"
        clicked={() => setCounter(state => state-1)}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="+ 5"
        clicked={() => setCounter(state => state+5)}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="- 5"
        clicked={() => setCounter(state => state-5)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

If you want to DRY it out a little more you could always do something like this:

```js
  const change = by => () => setCounter(count => count+by)

  return (
    <div className={classes.Counter}>
      <CounterOutput value={counter} />
      <CounterControl
        label="+"
        clicked={change(1)}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="-"
        clicked={change(-1)}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="+ 5"
        clicked={change(5)}
      />
      <CounterControl
        label="- 5"
        clicked={change(-5)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```